# Split page down the center. Fill left side with image and right side with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm fairly familiar with bootstrap 5 but I'm working on a project and I'm trying to figure out the best way to split the page down the center,but then also have a container in the middle that allows for a boundary that the text will not expand past.
The container width should be 1400px that's my current width that is defining the page.
What I'd like to do is almost a

```
<div class="container"> 1400px wide centered on page
<div class="col">Image that fills the left side to the edge</div>
<div class="col">Text that is bound within the 1400px container</div>
</div>
```

I tried putting an image set to no padding. But the text on the right goes beyond the 1400px container.

[image: Photo center]

Comment: Are you open to using any CSS properties? E.g. flex or grid properties?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row hero-height">
        <div class="col p-0 hero_image_top h-100" style="max-width: 50%;"></div>
        <div class="col text-center pt-5 px-0 clearfix" style="max-width: 700px;float: left; ">Copy Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```